How to remove the line between multiple cells in the same column?
I have a table where I want to remove the yellow lines. This is because those cells (in the same column) have the same value. As such, I also would like to keep one unique value in the merged cell.

Could you please elaborate on how to do so? Thank you so much for your help!
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
\textbf{Result} & \textbf{Assumption} & \textbf{Content} \\
\hline   \hline 
a &  & b \\ 
\hline 
c & D & e \\
\hline
f & D & g \\
\hline 
h & I & j \\ 
\hline 
k & I & l \\ 
\hline
m & I & n \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}


You can use package multirow to create multi-row cells and the command cline to make partial horizontal lines. See the code below or this reply for more complete examples.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| } 
\hline
\textbf{Result} & \textbf{Assumption} & \textbf{Content} \\
\hline   \hline 
a &  & b \\ 
\hline 
c & \multirow{2}*{D} & e \\
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
f &  & g \\
\hline 
h & \multirow{3}*{I} & j \\ 
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
k &  & l \\ 
\cline{1-1}\cline{3-3}
m &  & n \\ 
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}



Thank you so much for your help!
